# Finding the positive integers that can be written in the form $x^2+xy+5y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I'm working on a homework problem that asks which positive integers can be written in the form $x^2+xy+5y^2$. An example was given on how to find all positive integers that can be written as the difference of two squares (i.e. $x^2-y^2$), but it was a proof by cases that doesn't seem to carry over to more generalized versions of the form $ax^2+bx+cy^2$.

Is there any method to approaching these kinds of problems?

Comment: Divide by $x^2$ and let $y/x=t$.

Comment: Then, $1+\frac{y}{x}+5\frac{y^2}{x^2}=1+t+5t^2$. What do I do next?

Comment: can $x,y$ be negative?

Comment: @Yesit'sme The problem doesn't specify, so I'm guessing yes.

Comment: Write $N = x^2 + xy + 5y^2$. Solve the quadratic equation for $x$. Find the $N$ such that the solutions for $x$ are integers.

Comment: $x^2+xy+5y^2=\left(x+\dfrac y2\right)^2+\dfrac{19}4y^2=a^2+19b^2$

Comment: Assume $y=2z$ is even. Then rewrite as $(x+z)^2+19z^2$. Substitute $x+z$ by $t$. You need to find numbers represented by $t^2+19z^2$. This is standard. Then assume $y=2z+1$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this text](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:308f54a5-5f2e-4706-bfbe-12d1c13adbfd). It describes precisely which numbers are represented by a binary quadratic form (Proposition 4.1). In your case the discriminant is $-19$, so a number $n$ is represented by your form iff $-19$ is a square modulo $4n$. You can conclude by using the Gauss reciprocity law.

Comment: Can the result be broken down further into the prime divisors of $n$?

Comment: That is what the Gauss reciprocity law does.

Comment: To use the result in that text don't we also need to show that this is the unique reduced BQF of discriminant -19 (equiv there is only 1 $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ orbit of BQFs)? We are only guaranteed representability by *some* BQF of disc -19.

Comment: Then this only allows you to conclude something about "given $n$ is there a BQF $f(x,y)$ of disc $D$ such that $n$ is repd by $f$"? Which, I think, is not the general question OP wanted answered.

Comment: A counterexample in the class number not $1$ case is $x^2 + 5y^2$ (discriminant $-20$) and $n = 3$ then $-20 \equiv 4 \pmod{12}$ but is not represented (it is represented by the other reduced form of disc $-20$, namely $2x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2$)

Comment: Counterexample to Prop 4.1 from the text?

Comment: Not to the proposition, but to your interpenetration of it. Prop 4.1 says "for a given $n$ and $d$ *there exists* a BQF of discriminant $d$ which represents $n$ iff ..." In the example I gave $3$ was represented by a BQF of disc $-20$ (as the Prop guarantees), it just happened not to be in the orbit of the BQF I wanted. At least how I read it OP wanted to know "given some fixed BQF which $n$ does it represent"

Comment: In the OP case it is fine though.

Comment: Yes in the OP case $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ has class number $1$ (equiv a unique reduced BQFs of disc $-19$ - the one OP listed) so the exists is enough. I just don't think that it answers the question "is there a general method of approaching these problems" - which there is but one must think about hilbert class fields when $h_K \neq 1$

Comment: So you object that I do nor mention that -19 has class number 1?  It is one of the 9 Gauss  numbers.

Comment: @JCAA I don't object to your answer on the whole. I was mainly concerned that you do not make it clear that having "some" BQF of correct discriminant is enough (because you can check that it is the only one of disc -19 satisfying equation 4.1.1 in your linked document - which is equivalent to $h_K =1$, I am pointing out the class number stuff only to show how the counterexample comes about)

Comment: I agree, I should have mentioned that. I was not sure the OP has studied class numbers. The OP said that only some basic examples were taught in class so far.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a few methods mentioned, so I hope you will forgive me if I mention a sophisticated but fun approach.

Let $x^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be the binary quadratic form of discriminant $d = b^2 - 4c < 0$ such that
$$ b = \cases{0 \quad d \equiv 2, 3 \pmod{4}  \\ 1 \quad d \equiv 1 \pmod{4}}$$

Note that we are in this case since $d = 1 - 20 = -19 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. There is a fun result

> **Thm** A prime $p \nmid d$ is represented by our BQF if and only if $p$ splits completely in the *Hilbert Class Field* of $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$

For those who have not seen it before, we have the following

> **Fact:** The Hilbert Class Field is an abelian extension of degree $h_L$ (the class number of $L$).

In our case this gives a way to derive the result since $p$ is represented if and only if $p$ splits (completely) in $\mathcal{O}_L$ where $L = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ (this is because $h_L = 1$). If $p \neq 19$ we see that this is the case if and only if the polynomial $x^2 + 19$ splits mod $p$. This is if and only if $-19$ is a square mod $p$.