# Integers not representable by $x^2 + axy - y^2$

Tags: quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

Given that no ternary quadratic form is universal and given the form $x^2 + axy - y^2$, how do I go about determining the integers that are *not representable* by that form?

Using the **[Conway-Schneeberger 15-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems)**, if the quadratic form represents all integers from the set $\{1,2,3,5,6,7,10,14,15\}$, it is univeral (i.e., represents all positive integers) and if there is only one integer $x$ in this set that is not representable then there is a quadratic form that represents all integers in that set other than $x$.

**Questions:**

1. How do I apply this to determine integers *not representable* by $x^2 + axy - y^2$?
2. Can this be addressed for general $a$? If not, can we solve this for specific $a$ such as, how do we determine integers *not representable* by $x^2 + 4xy - y^2$

Comment: The case $a=4$ can be solved by considering the equation modulo $3$. The only solution modulo $3$ is $x=y=0$ , hence $3$ is not representable. No idea whether an analogue method works in general for other $a$.

Comment: I state an important result in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770518/finding-the-positive-integers-that-can-be-written-in-the-form-x2xy5y2/3770583#3770583) answer. Notice that the discriminant in your case is $a^2 + 4$ is not negative so the result does not apply - but this gives an idea of how tricky such problems can be in general.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey: So, I should be able to use (from the link) 

**Proposition 4.1.** Integer $n$ is properly represented by some binary quadratic form of discriminant $d$ if and only if $d$ is a square mod $4n$.

Comment: @wgiri no I am referring to my answer to that question. In particular the fact that even in the negative discriminant case we need to pull out big hammers like class field theory - so there is unlikely to be an easy solution to your question for arbitrary $a$.

Comment: Using brute force I think $2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15$ are not represented by $x^2+4 x y-y^2$

Comment: Integers of the form $4n+2$ are not representable by $x^2+4xy-y^2$.

Comment: More generally, if $a\equiv 0\pmod 4$, then integers of the form $4n+2$ are not representable by $x^2+axy−y^2$.